# Ubuntu for Meizu Mx Pro 5 - Android Edition?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

I own **Meizu MX Pro 5**, regular **Android edition**.

Now that the MX Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition is coming out, I wonder if I could **install Ubuntu-Touch using dualboot** on my MX Pro 5 - or at least install Ubuntu-Touch.

Any **suggestions?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android