# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Phone how reinstall the device

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a problem with my Ubuntu phone Meizu pro 5, when I'm turning it on, the
screen "Meizu powered by Ubuntu" is appearing but nothing is happening after.
How can I reinstall my Ubuntu phone ?

Thanks in advance to everyone for help.

Comment: Please, could you add details about what is happened last time that you were able to  use your smartphone?

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

I did the command "sudo apt-get remove openvpn" and since nothing is working.

Here's a video : https://yadi.sk/i/pN4ClCfDrwBPC

Comment: Did you try to reinstall `openvpn`? Maybe removing it, has also removed some packages that your phone needs to work properly.

Comment: The phone isn't booting anymore so I can't try to reinstall any packages. /:

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, maybe you need to reinstall the Ubuntu system, and I encountered similar issue a few days ago, I upgraded it on my Ubuntu desktop, but unfortunately, it failed, and then the phone can not launch any more.

and finally I have re-installed the Ubuntu system for my pro5 by following this solution [How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android) . Hope it help you.

and the main steps that I used is as below (I did that under the Ubuntu desktop environment):

1. flash the recovery to pro5
   (sudo fastboot flash recovery TWRP_3.0_m86.img)
2. prepare the kernel*.zip
   remember to replace the 4 files, which come your device*.tar.xz.
3. prepare the Ubuntu*.tar.xz, device*.tar.xz, customer*.tar.xz, version*.tar.xz
4. reboot to recovery mode, and than install the kernel, mount the system folder, uncompress Ubuntu*.tar.xz, device*.tar.xz, customer*.tar.xz, version*.tar.xz
5. reboot the phone, and then my phone is back to work.