# Meizu Pro 5 ubuntu - forgotten passphrase

Tags: ubuntu-touch, password-recovery, reset

I forgot the passphrase I set and I am stuck at the lock screen.
How to either reset the device or somehow bypass the lock screen.

Googling my problem, various places suggest turning it off and then  volume up + power  buttons to get to some menu in order to do hard reset. But all I get is the ubuntu logo (just the image) on a purple screen and nothing else - no menu. Waited for awhile - nothing happened. Then if i hold the power button again, it gets back to the normal booting process and gets to the lock screen again, asking for the password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my pro5 was stuck in logo screen, maybe by upgrading failed, and I follow the solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android), then my phone is come back to working now. Hope it can help you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I hope I find time to try it soon. My research was getting me towards similar or even the same article but was too much stuff to read and adapt to my case.