# How to re-install Ubuntu touch to my Ubuntu Edition Pro5

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, recovery-mode

now the phone is stuck in logo screen for upgrading failed, and now I can only enter the fastboot mode. Is there any way to re-install the Ubuntu touch for my phone? Looking forward to your feedback, thanks in advance.

Later, I trying Ubuntu-device-flash command to rescue, but the error say "Can't boot recovery image", any feedback is highly appreciated.
Noted: I have flash the recovery-turbo.img to the phone for fixing the "Failed to enter recovery" issue.

Comment: I have fixed it with the solution from http://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android