# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm attempting to locate a Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition Phone so I can find Australian prices, and purchase.

All the sites I've been to in an attempt to locate a Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition Phone, state that the Operating System is Android Operating System version 5.1 series of Lollipop.

See [this site](http://www.mobilewithprices.com/meizu-mx-pro-5-ubuntu-edition-2810-in-australia-5010.php) as an example

What's going on?

Comment: I do not see any option to buy it though.

Answer (score 1):

I did see on another post here that someone said that there were going to be no more Pro 5's released. However, there would be more Ubuntu edition phones released in time. How long that will be is currently unclear. I do see that there are a few people on here that wish that had of got the Pro 5 and therefore I would imagine will jump on the new phones when released.

Comment: This is a great shame as I am currently looking to get one. The only option I can see is buying a Pro 5 with andriod and then putting Touch on it. At through moment none of the phones are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy Pro5 Android version and install Ubuntu by yourself.

[How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android)

And it works also on 64 GB 4GB RAM version as well.

Comment: This is a great post as there seems to be a fair few people wanted one but missed out, due to the short period it was on sale for. I persobally liked the spec for the price and this would be a valid option.

Comment: Stef01, Thanks I didn't know that. However the phone or phones are not for me, they are for people for whom this is not an option. Additionally, even if it was for me it's not an option I would choose. I could quite easily buy a laptop with Windows on it and install my choice of Linux, but instead I choose to buy laptops with Linux pre installed. I prefer not to send the wrong message to the manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this the other day, it may be a possible solution to the issue of not being able to locate any more Pro 5's. The Meizu MX6 Ubuntu Edition looks like it might be here soon. However, at the moment it is not clear if the 4G LTE will work outside of China. [The Meizu MX6 Made Official, Ubuntu Edition ‘Coming Soon’](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/meizu-mx6-official-announcement-specs)