# Can Ubuntu Touch be installed on 64GB memory version of Meizu Pro 5?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

In a couple of months I'm intending to buy a Meizu Pro 5 and install Ubuntu Touch. This phone comes in two hardware versions: 64gb memory with 4gb ram or 32gb with 3gb ram. The Meizu Pro 5 with 32gb/3gb was previously sold as an ubuntu edition and there are official images and repositories available to install Ubuntu onto this device even if originally sold with Android/Flyme. (see for example [How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android?rq=1)).

However, I have nowhere found any descriptions which explicitly state that ubuntu touch was being installed onto the other 64gb/4gb version and I find this more powerful version is widely available second-hand where I live (Italy) whereas the other version seems rare.

So basically my question is can the image available in the Ubuntu repositories (e.g https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) be installed onto the 64GB/4GB RAM version?

Given that my understanding is that ubuntu touch images have to be closely tailored to the phablet hardware, I suspect that the answer is no: I previously installed Ubuntu Touch on the LTE version of the 2013 Nexus 7, and that requires an entirely different image from that required for the wifi only version.

Unless someone tells me otherwise, I think I am safer buying the 32gb/3gb version. I'm no great expert though so if anyone has successfully managed to get Ubuntu working on the 64gb version then please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. I unfortunatelly cannot help you. However, are you sure that the Android/Flyme version comes with an unlocked bootloader and that it can be flashed? Could you add some links to your question?

Comment: Yes,  it seems the bootloader can be unlocked and it can be flashed, for instance see these links: http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/tutorial-change-region-id-to-t3323883, http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-mx/general/recovery-twrp-3-0-meizu-pro5-t3349888/post66148672#post66148672,  http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-mx/general/recovery-twrp-3-0-meizu-pro5-t3349888/post66148672#post66148672,

Comment: Also see the answers to this askubuntu question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes is the answer as I just done that yesterday have a look here, there is the proof that I have install it to 64GB 4GB RAM Meizu Pro5 which was originally Android.

here is the photo of my PRO5 64GB, 4GB RAM

https://plus.google.com/u/0/101216811071065193275/posts/H8Q6AUgf1jG?pid=6311591721134846306&oid=101216811071065193275