# Meizu Pro5 update fails (Android originally), no way to do ubuntu-device-flash

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was wondering if anyone have a suggestion or a solution to following issue.
I have installed Ubuntu Touch on Meizu Pro5 which was Android originally as is described here: 
[How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android)
The installation was easy, the real bummer here is to find a way how to managed to install it just like it was a native Ubuntu Touch device.
I have manually flashed the turbo recovery and tried from there.
The adb recognise the device and u-d-f manages to download and push all files to the device and it even reboots to recovery, then for a second is shown the progress bar in recovery (just like normal update on Mx4 ) and immediately after that it shows the image ,,update failed'' contact support.

I have tried to wipe it, bootstrap it, add --recovery-image  option, even tried a different channels recovery e.g Devel/Rc-proposed, but nothing works.

Tried to look for a log files but couldn't find any. 
Anyone has an idea what to do or how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for some reason `busybox` supplied with said recovery is outdated and unsupported. So updater simply can not unpack modern `xz` tar archive. You need to help it do this manually:

after you get to the error updating screen - do this:

1. download `busybox-armv7l` from https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/
2. push busybox as tar: `adb push ~/ubuntutouch/busybox-armv7l /sbin/tar`
3. `adb shell`
4. in adb shell (everything below is in adb shell) - `chmod a+x /sbin/tar`
5. mount `/system` as described in file /fstab.m86 on device (`cp /fstab.m86 /etc/fstab; mount -a`)
6. (delete all files in /system if needed `rm -rf /system/*`)
7. `cd /cache/recovery`
8. import keys `tar -xvf image-signing.tar.xz keyring.gpg -O | gpg --import` and `tar -xvf image-master.tar.xz keyring.gpg -O | gpg --import`
9. unpack system image:

`tar xf ubuntu-* -C /
tar xf device-* -C /
tar xf custom-* -C /
tar xf version-* -C /
sync
umount /system`

reboot with power button, wait 5 minutes to finish install.

I do not know if this will support OTA, but at least it is all done with ubuntu utilities (and hands) only

I guess someone should file a bug about broken busybox in published recovery.

Comment: Thanks, but in a meantime I have managed to update via OTA. Yes, u-d-f still dont work and still shows update failed message, I might give it a try later with the instructions you provided.

Comment: grandrew have you tried it on your phone and after the ubuntu-device-flash worked normally?

Comment: yes, I have managed to install everything on my phone using ubuntu-device-flash and ubuntu recovery. However, I can not say "it works normally" as the said recovery does not work without manual unpacking of the archives as described in my post. I have not tried re-upgrading ubuntu though - I just made sure that my method works in the scenario you initially described.

Comment: So if I do the manual unpacking of busybox, then ubuntu-device-flash should finally work, right? Cos OTA works normally. Just u-d-f is gives me a grief and I need that to be working , cos I'm gonna play a little bit with desktop apps and do some modification, so when I break something I can always just flash it manually.

Comment: BusyBox v1.22.1 static (2016-06-17 07:41 +0000) multi-call binary. This is the version provided by the recovery. I have tried to update it as you described above, but I am unable to do so. I have tied that with working system, in recovery via adb. Should I only do it when the update failed screen shown? step 5 is confusing don't know what to do with it.

Comment: As I understand this will wipe the phone and install whole os again, right? Sorry for bothering you with so many questions.

Comment: 1. the problem is not the version but absence of xz feature. This should be configured at build time of busybox and recovery comes with a misconfigured one.; 2. you should only do that in an "update failed screen".; 3. `cp /fstab.m86 /etc/fstab; mount -a` should work for step 5 however I do not recall the exact name for fstab file at / - you should better do `ls /` and see how it is called; 4. this will not wipe anything simply because recovery does not work ;-) if it worked it would've wiped though.

Comment: ~ # cp /fstab.m86 /etc/fstab; mount -a
mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/recovery on /recovery failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/ldfw on /ldfw failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/dtb on /dtb failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/custom on /custom failed: No such file or directory

Comment: trying to mount system gives me: ~ # mount system
mount: mounting /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/system on /system failed: Device or resource busy

Comment: I tried every option possible, even tried do it within working recovery, but no, no luck. I guess I will have to leave it as is then. But thank for the help along the way.

Comment: from what you posted here it seems that mounting went okay; you need to unpack the images now. Mounting `dtb`, `custom`, etc. is not required, you just have to make sure that `/system` is mounted. The process is very straightforward and there is very little that can go wrong.