# How to update meizu pro 5

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch, tar

I have installed ubuntu by follow this guide

[How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android)

or to be more correct, mixed with this

> I was able to install ubuntu OTA11 using this tutorial. I did not read the articles from (4.) here is what I did: 1. unlock using xda links 1-3, press home-power-down for recovery mode TWRP 2. copied via USB all ubuntu OTA-11 files to TWRP folder. 3. Installed everything as said 4. unpacked not using tar -vxf but just tar -xf /sdcard/TWRP/... (10x times faster), reboot! – grandrew Jun 28 at 20:50`

Now I have ota-11, but I would of course like to update, and as it says here, it's possible

> For those interested in OTA updates - in this method you should do it manually. Ubuntu will download OTA files to /cache/recovery. You need to manually unpack them. After you tap "install and reboot" in ubuntu updater - system will boot into custom loader. Mount system and unpack new files using tar as said in main post using advanced->terminal. – grandrew Aug 2 at 10:29`

I checked /cache/recovery after I tapped "install and reboot" ,and it was quit a lot of files there.

I am little bit unsure which files I should "tar".

1. Can I cd to recovery and "tar" there, does it work like that?
2. It is also tar.xz.asc and tar.xz files there, but I guess tar.xz.asc is some kind of signatur. So if I have understood it correctly, the only files I "tar" in recovery is the tar.xz
3. Do I only "tar" the 4 as in the guide or do I include image-master.tar.xz and image-signing.tar.xz? If that is the case, in which order do I "tar" them?
4. It's also some more files there, `ubuntu_command, .version, last_log, log, recovery.fstab, storage.fstab` Can I ignore them?
5. When I am done (however it's going to work) can I wipe cache?

I now it was a lot of question, but if it works, at least I have understood a little bit more about the Ubuntu phone and maybe I don't brick it yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that updating via TWRP terminal works just fine. I have done myself on my Pro5. Just do exactly as you did when installing and only those 4 files. The system will be updated and all data will be kept intact. 
When finished you can wipe the cache.
No need to worry about bricking the phone, not this way at least:-)

Comment: I solved it different, by following the steps I did here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68362682&postcount=56           so after I flashed with sudo fastboot flash recovery recovery.img I'm able to upgrade over OTA

Comment: I was to slow to edit the comment.  Thanks for the info, it's good to now how to do it manually.

Comment: What exactly did you do to manage make OTA upgrades work? Do you have 32GB 3GB Ram phone or 64GB 4GB Ram version? Because I have tried everything possible to make it work and nothing. Adb recognise the device, recovery can be flashed and once the OTA downloads, it reboot and a second after fails. It's driving me crazy this failure.

Comment: I have the 64GB and 4GB Ram version. I think the only difference I did compared to you (I'm assuming) is step 6-8 in this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68362682&postcount=56

Comment: And where is the backup from that you have restored? Should I restore my phone with TWRP? But I don't have a backup from Pleytos TWRPBACKUPmeizu5pro UBUNTU.. Apart from that I have done exactly all that before and even flashed ubuntu recovery after. And it did not work. Could you clarify where should I get that backup from and what else should I do as I'm little confused what to do right now. Thanks.

Comment: The backup file I used is from Pleytos and if you look at this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67713435&postcount=20  you should be able to download it and I restored it with TWRP. I wish I could help more, but the only thing I did was to follow the guides and mix them a little bit. I do remember that I wiped all that I could before I restored it.

Comment: My only concern  when restoring this backup is IMEI might be replaced or am I wrong? And when restoring a 32 GB device backup to 64 GB device the partition table might be different. Is your still listed as 64 GB?

Comment: About IMEI number I wouldn't now. I didn't look at it before I started, so I don't now if it has changed from the originally android phone. I can see that I have 2 IMEI numbers, probably because of 2 sim-card trays. The phone is still 64 GB device.

Comment: Yeah, that backup worked. Strange. IMEI did not changed. I restored the backup and then did update and it updated successfully to OTA-12, then I flashed recovery.img, but when trying to manually update with u-d-f got a error, device can't be reached over adb. I'll try again. And maybe it is a problem with the usb -c cable, it's a bit loose, I'll get a new one and hopefully it will work. Anyway, thank you Tom for your help.

Comment: Great it worked. I flashed recovery.img before I updated to OTA12, but if that makes any difference I don't know. And my IMEI numbers didn't change either, I just checked the box :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made an OTA upgrade

1. download the ota using the update manager on the phone (do not click on install)
2. reboot into recovery
3. make a backup of the current installation
4. mount the system partition
5. login to the phone using `adb shell` (or open the command line in twrp)
6. cd into the recovery directory
   `cd /cache/recovery`
7. check that you have the needed files
   `ls -lh`

   You should have the following files

   - ubuntu-aaa.delta-ubuntu-aaa.tar.xz
   - device-aaa.delta-device-aaa.tar.xz
   - custom-aaa.delta-custom-aaa.tar.xz
   - version-aaa.tar.xz

(instead of aaa there will be a long hash)

8. install the update using the following comands

   ```
   tar xf ubuntu-*.tar.xz -C /
   tar xf device-*.tar.xz -C /
   tar xf custom-*.tar.xz -C /
   tar xf version-*.tar.xz -C /
   sync
   ```
9. exit adb
10. wipe cache
11. reboot the system

Comment: At one upgrade some files were missing when I flashed the delta files so I had to flash the full upgrade files after the delta files too. See: [System Settings screen blank after Ubuntu Phone upgrade on Meizu Pro 5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/830154/system-settings-screen-blank-after-ubuntu-phone-upgrade-on-meizu-pro-5)