# System Settings screen blank after Ubuntu Phone upgrade on Meizu Pro 5

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch

I'm using a 64GB Meizu Pro 5.
I had it running with OTA-12 without any problems.
Because I did not flash the Pro 5 boot loader I had to upgrade the OTA manually as described in [How to update meizu pro 5](https://askubuntu.com/a/830147/533912)

After restarting the device the applications work but whenever I go into any System Settings window it stays completely blank.

I wiped the cache and data (making a factory reset in TWRP) but the problem persists.

When I flash ubuntu-*.tar.xz I get the following message:
`tar: can't remove old file system/usr/share/doc/libtelepathy-qt5-0: Is a directory`

Here the log after opening the system settings:

```
2016-09-28 14:40:32,101 - WARNING - "No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /"
2016-09-28 14:40:32,110 - WARNING - "No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1"
2016-09-28 14:40:32,115 - WARNING - "No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0"
2016-09-28 14:40:32,132 - WARNING - Attempted to deliver an event to a non-existent window, ignoring.

** (process:6339): WARNING **: Unable to submit Zeitgeist Event: The connection is closed

(process:6339): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_array_free: assertion 'array' failed
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Terminated
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
qrc:/qml/MainWindow.qml:22:1: module "SystemSettings.ListItems" is not installed
```

Has anyone upgraded from OTA-12 to OTA-13 successfully?
What do I need to change in order to make the System Settings window appear?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two of what's wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately a screenshot wouldn't show much. The whole settings screen is just white. No icons, no text. No matter how I access it. E.g. when I open the top notification area and click on About this device, mobile settings, etc.

Comment: It'd really help if you could show us your /home/phablet/.cache/upstart/application-legacy-ubuntu-system-settings-.log — Thanks!

Comment: I added the log to the original question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the folder /usr/share/ubuntu/settings/system/qml-plugins/SystemSettings/ListItems/ and all its files was missing.

I was able to fix this by doing

1. flash the OTA-13 delta files
2. reboot into the system
3. flash the full OTA-13 files

(flashing the full OTA-13 directly over OTA-12 would make make the phone fail at boot time)