# Meizu 5 pro to Ubuntu (Originally with Flyme)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, internationalization

Now I know that this question was kinda answered by the following thread

[How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android)

I am very new to messing with phones in general and have very little experience with Android so I am pretty lost.

Pretty much I ordered an international version of the Meizu 5 pro off ebay (at least I think it's the international version because it has the 2 sim card slots and 64gb, but now I'm thinking that it is the chinese version as there is alot of chinese)

So after receiving the international version I did a hard reset and pretty much I'm stuck on the first part of the guide as I don't even know how to downgrade my flyme OS to the 5.1.3.0A or root my phone or connect it to my computer (Which i'm running ubuntu btw) I even got stuck just trying to download the google play store on the phone!

If anyone can please offer some guidance I would greatly appreciate it and I'll throw in a 25$ amazon gift card. Here are some google drive links to pictures below that should help give context to whats going on

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NHvqtRdB7j6tc_ykv1Od8KBuUTtKqQG2?usp=sharing

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: This isn't really a question with a straightforward answer, so the best places to ask would either be at https://forums.ubports.com or the [UBports Welcome & Install Telegram Group](https://t.me/WelcomePlus).